# Remove all but the website name from URL in Ruby

Tags: ruby, url, gsub

Im a iterating through a list of URLs. The urls come in different formats like:

```
https://twitter.com/sdfaskj... 
https://www.linkedin.com/asdkfjasd...
http://google.com/asdfjasdj...
```

etc.

I would like to use Gsub or something similar to erase everything but the name of the website, to get only "twitter", "linkedin", and "google", respectively.

In my head, ideally I would like something like a .gsub that can check for multiple possibilities (url.gsub("https:// or https://www. or http:// etc.", "") and replace them when found with nothing "". Also it needs to delete everything after the name, so ".com/wkadslflj..."

```
attributes.css("a").each do |attribute|
  attribute_url = attribute["href"]
  attribute_scrape = attribute_url.gsub("https://", "")
  binding.pry
end
```

Answer (score 6):

I would consider a combination of `URI.parse` to get the hostname from the URL and the [`PublicSuffix`](https://github.com/weppos/publicsuffix-ruby) gem to get the second level domain:

```
require 'public_suffix'
require 'uri'

url  = 'https://www.linkedin.com/asdkfjasd'
host = URI.parse(url).host                 # => 'www.linkedin.com'
PublicSuffix.parse(host).sld               # => 'linkedin'
```

Comment: Personally I'd ditch the gem and do `host.split(?.)[-2]`. The domain name spec is pretty stable.

Comment: @Max `split(?.)[-2]` doesn't reliably return the most important part of the domain, for example, for valid domains like `www.google.com.au` or `www.amazon.co.uk` it would return `com` or `co`. Whereas the `PublicSuffix` gem would return `google` and `amazon`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `gsub` regexp :

`gsub(/http(s)?:\/\/(www.)?|.(com|net|co.uk|us)+.*/, '')`

Output:

```
list = ["https://twitter.com/sdfaskj...", "https://www.linkedin.com/asdkfjasd...", "http://google.com/asdfjasdj..."] 

list.map { |u| u.gsub(/http(s)?:\/\/(www.)?|.(com|net|co.uk|us)+.*/, '') }
 => ["twitter", "linkedin", "google"]
```

Comment: That worked! I'm going to have to study that regex line...

Comment: could be a lot less complicated with the `URI` module and `host`

Comment: `URI.parse("https://www.twitter.com/sdfaskj...").host` returns `www.twitter.com` not `twitter`

Comment: @AlexKojin and doesn't that look easier to parse? Also what about other subdomains and tlds?

Comment: @engineersmnky it's solution for this spec not for all cases. It works and took 2 minutes to write and check this.